# Line Integrals - Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, polar-coordinates

I have a problem asking me to find $\int_C \textbf{f} \cdot d\textbf{r}$ where $\textbf{f}$ = $(\sin y,x\cos y)$, and the curve $C$ is any closed circle.

I'm struggling with this, so far I have found that $d\textbf{r}$ is $(-rsin\theta,rcos\theta)d\theta$, which is then $(-y,x)d\theta$ in cartesian coordinates.

I then tried to do the following; $\int_0^{2\pi} (\sin y,x\cos y) \cdot (-y,x)d\theta$, but I'm not making any progress and I'm unsure whether my method is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not applying the formula for line integrals correctly.  Remember that it's $$\int_C \mathbf f\cdot d\mathbf r = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathbf f(\mathbf x(t))\cdot \mathbf x'(t)\ dt$$

where $C$ is parametrized by $\mathbf x(t)$ over $t\in [t_0, t_1]$.  Notice that the only variable is $t$ (you can't mix in three different variables like you do in your proposed integral).

**However**, that's not the way to do this problem.  The most reasonable parametrization of a circle leads to an integral that is very difficult to solve.  Instead:

**Hint**: What do you know about the value of a line integral $\int_C \mathbf f\cdot d\mathbf r$ over a closed curve $C$ when $\mathbf f$ is a *conservative field*?  Is there a way to check whether this is a conservative field?

Comment: Ok I see where I went wrong, thank you.

Comment: Is the answer 0 although a full circle isn't continuous?

Comment: The answer is $0$.  What do you mean a full circle isn't continuous?

Comment: Because surely at the full rotation it takes the same value at $2\pi$ as it does at $0$?

Comment: So, for example say I parametrized my integral as $x = a + cos(t)$ and $y = b + sin(t)$, then $t$ is not continuous on a full loop of a circle?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with continuity.  The main take-away is that because $\mathbf f$ is a conservative field the gradient theorem applies.  And because a circle is a *closed curve* the line integral evaluates to $0$.